# Kiwi TCMS Python API Connection SSL error

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm getting following error when I try to run the tcms-api module but following the steps given,

https://tcms-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms_api.html#module-tcms_api

I'm using python 3 in CentOS, applied our own domain and certificates by mounting the certificates to docker container.

Can you please tell how to solve the SSL Certificate verification failure error?

```
[root@KiwiTCMS-Testcase-Portal docker-compose]# python3 test-api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-api.py", line 5, in <module>
    rpc_client = TCMS()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tcms_api/__init__.py", line 123, in __init__
    config['tcms']['url']).server
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tcms_api/xmlrpc.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.login(username, password, url)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tcms_api/xmlrpc.py", line 131, in login
    self.server.Auth.login(username, password)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in single_request
    http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1279, in send_request
    self.send_content(connection, request_body)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1309, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1282, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1042, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1448, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using Python 3.6 from RedHat's SoftwareCollections. That version contains a bug (or arguably a security feature) which doesn't respect settings documented in upstream Python which allow you to accept untrusted SSL certificates.  There are lots of these things reported on bugzilla.redhat.com but I don't think they will change it!

This is how we do it in our test suite:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/tcms-api/blob/master/tests/krb5/integration_test.py#L18

Answer (score 2):

Introducing the following line fix the issue,

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```